# Some man pages not found

Tags: ubuntu, manpage, size-t, unistd.h

Ubuntu 12.04...

I had fedora a couple of years back and I saw the man pages for the following there...

```
unistd.h,
sys/types.h,
standard typedefs (suffixed by "_t") etc.
```

I tried this...

`man unistd`

But it didn't find it :(

I think those pages are not there in Ubuntu.

Although `man stdio` works and other man pages are there.

So

- if Ubuntu doesn't have those pages, please tell me how to download them
- And what is the command for viewing standard typedef man page ie man page for `size_t`, `pid_t`, `off_t`, `clock_t` etc.

I trid `man stddef` but not found...

Comment: I actually know that this is a better fit for askubuntu.com but I had no reply there :( and indeed it is about programming...

Comment: Have you asked superuser.com?

Comment: No. Is that a better fit for superuser.com?

 if so I will ask there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This is what needed to do...

`sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev`

to get those pages :)